# Can someone provide input how to modify imacro script

Tags: imacros

I have created imacro script for posting a content (for my job) and its doing fine. Problem is that is hard to edit content links are always the same. 
So my problem is that I have 134 URLs go to, in which I copy paste tags to get script to work. Somehow I have felling that there must be faster way to do same thing.

Only change is on URK go to, different town inforont ogasi.org

```
    VERSION BUILD=8070701 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=http://beli-manastir.oglasi.org/predajaoglasa?kateg=osobni-kontakti
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=ID:naslov CONTENT=xyxyxy
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=ID:tekst CONTENT=MY CONTENT BLA BLA
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=ID:ime CONTENT=<SP>
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=ID:tel CONTENT=<SP>
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=NAME:email CONTENT=MY MAIL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=ID:email_lathato CONTENT=NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=NAME:ecode CONTENT=PASS
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=ID:uslovi CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=*
URL GOTO=http://belisce.oglasi.org/predajaoglasa?kateg=osobni-kontakti
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=ID:naslov CONTENT=xyxyxy
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=ID:tekst CONTENT=MY CONTENT BLA BLA
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=ID:ime CONTENT=<SP>
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=ID:tel CONTENT=<SP>
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=NAME:email CONTENT=MY MAIL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=ID:email_lathato CONTENT=NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=NAME:ecode CONTENT=PASS
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=ID:uslovi CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:sampleform ATTR=*
```

Answer (score 0):

Save all the URLs in a CSV file and loop through the file using this type of code:

http://wiki.imacros.net/Demo-Loop-Csv-2-Web